# Godot generated apk size too big

Tags: godot

I have just started experimenting with godot. What I notice apk size generated by godot is too big which is 10MB considering fact my game does nothing it only moves some random blocks up and deletes itself.
I have generated only ARM64 in release mode .What I am missing?
Do I need to recompile godot with by disabling unwanted things?

Comment: Is it safe to assume you've applied all the [size optimizations recommended in the documentation here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/optimizing_for_size.html)?

Comment: No I haven't done that. So I need to recompile godot?

Comment: If you're looking for ways to reduce the size, following the documented recommendations for reducing the size sounds like a reasonable starting point. By my reading of the doc, it sounds like it's recompiling your project, not recompiling Godot itself.

Comment: First of all Thank you for your time this matters me a lot! I think above documentation is about compiling godot itself. Cuz I have came across that documentation before, tried to execute  command given in doc on project root folder it didn't work. Later I downloaded godot source then ran the command in doc on root of godot src it worked perfectly godot binary was created. I'm student I have less development experience, so any guidance could help.

Comment: You might be able to get around 7-8 MB by compiling an Android export template with unneeded features disabled, but I don't think you can really get below that size. You might be able to run ProGuard during the build process as described here, but beware as it can introduce runtime crashes due to classes being obfuscated when they shouldn't be: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/18253

Comment: What I observe after uncompressing apk is most of size is consumed by libgodot_android.so file (my case 75%+) .In what you said I don't understand what is Android export template or what is does. Can you please explain what it is and tell how to recompile it . I have heard Android export template but non explain what it is or how it works.You can tell those things answer section.

Comment: This is a problem you are going to encounter in most game engines. When you build a game, then all the features of the whole engine are added to the executable. Not just the functionality you are actually using. The reason is that it can actually be very difficult for the engine to make 100% sure that you are indeed not using a specific engine feature.

Comment: In the case of Unity, last I heard, the executable includes a player, and the chunk of data that specifies your game to the player. So a project that only shows a black screen will hit a minimum size: that of the player.